# Radius of the sphere inscribed at the corner of an irregular polyhedron

Tags: analytic-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

Does anyone know the mathematical formula to calculate the radius of a sphere that can be inscribed at the corner of an irregular polyhedron ? There can be several radius, but the sphere should not protrude out of the polyhedron. In 2D it looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyTyh.png). The radius is purely based on the corner angle. But I need for 3D where the corner vertex has n number of faces and the angles are not all equal (something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOhL2.png)).

Thank you in advance,
Sincerely,
Sumana

Comment: I don't think there is a "formula." Even an algorithm is not straightforward.

Comment: any hint about how to proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

> any hint about how to proceed ?

In general, I believe your sphere is constrained by $3$ of the $n$ planes
that form a corner. So here is one naive approach.

First, solve the problem for a corner comprised of three planes.
This amounts to finding the insphere for an irregular tetrahedron.
See the Mathematica SE posting,
"[Insphere for Irregular Tetrahedron](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33846/194)":

---

[image]

---

Second, for each of the $\binom{n}{3}$ triples of planes, solve for
the sphere.

Third, for each solution, check whether the other planes cut it.

Fourth, select among the uncut spheres supported by three planes.

A less naive approach would compute the medial axis of the convex cone,
which effectively yields all the maximal spheres.
Lastly, I suspect the problem can be solved by linear programming.